# What is the run-time complexity of the following algorithm, in terms of a and b?

Tags: python, time-complexity

I was wondering what the time complexity of this function would be in terms of two variables. My guess would be O(a*b), due to the while loop using a and b.

```
def somefunc(a, b):

    def anotherfunc(current, num_digits):

        if num_digits == 0:

            print(current)

        else:

            print_01_codes('0' + current, num_digits - 1)

            print_01_codes('1' + current, num_digits - 1)

    upper_bound = 0

    while True:

        for i in range(upper_bound):

            print_01_codes('', a)

        if upper_bound > b:

            break

        upper_bound += 1
```

Comment: What is `print_01_codes`? It's never defined.

Comment: Also, what are `a` and `b`? Clearly `b` is a positive integer, but `a` could be anything at all given the code you've shown us.

Comment: Is `anotherfunc` the function you're calling as `print_01_codes`? If so, I think your total runtime is `O(a * 2^a * b^2)`, but I'm not completely certain I'm analyzing the recursive function correctly. Copying the strings for the concatenation is something like `O(a)`, and you're recursing `O(2^a)` times for a single call from the outer function. The two loops in the outer function run `O(b^2)` times.

Answer (score 0):

Since `a` is never used to determine the number of iterations of your loops, the complexity should be `O(b^2)`, as the inner loop will iterate `b^2/2` times.

Answer (score 0):

Your outer `while True:` loop is effectively `for upper_bound in range(b+1):` written more obscurely, so it obviously runs `b+1` times.

Your inner loop is `for i in range(upper_bound):`, and `upper_bound` averages `(b+1)/2`, so it runs `(b+1)/2` times per outer loop, or `(b+1) * (b+1)/2` total.

You haven't shown us the definition of `print_01_codes('', a)`, or told us what the values of `a` and `b` are.

- If `a` is a collection of some kind, and `print_01_codes` loops over the values in `a` (just as, e.g., `print('', a)` would), that loop runs `a` times per inner loop, or `(b+1) * (b+1)/2 * a` total.
- If `a` is just a number, and it's just printed (just as, e.g., `print('', a)` would), that takes `log(a, 10)` time.

Meanwhile, all of that code in `anotherfunc` is irrelevant, because that function never gets called.

So, your time is not `O(a * b)`, but either `O(a * b**2)` or `O(log a * b**2)`.