# What is the run-time complexity of the following algorithm, in terms of n and m?

Tags: python, algorithm, big-o

```
def print_all_codes(n, m):

    def print_01_codes(current, num_digits):
        if num_digits == 0:
            print(current)
        else:
            print_01_codes('0' + current, num_digits - 1)
            print_01_codes('1' + current, num_digits - 1)

    upper_bound = 0

    while True:
        for i in range(upper_bound):
            print_01_codes('', n)

        if upper_bound > m:
            break

        upper_bound += 1
```

I have tried to solve this problem for a while and the only conclusion I came up with was: O(m*2^n)
I have seen the other problem that has a similar wording, but the conclusion to that problem was inconclusive. [Similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51373804/what-is-the-run-time-complexity-of-the-following-algorithm-in-terms-of-a-and-b)

Comment: How did you come up with your answer?

Comment: I know it runs at least m times. Then, it runs "print_01_codes" recursively, and some to most recursive functions run 2^n times. Also, I saw a similar solution on another site.

Comment: Make sure to account for the non-constant-time operations within `print_01_codes`. It's easy to overlook that each of the uses of `current` is `O(len(current))`.

Comment: " and some to most recursive functions run 2^n times" um, that is definitely not a valid inference.

Answer (score 0):

The while loop is essentially 1+2+...+M times and O(M^2).
The print_01_codes print all binomial possibilities of n-bit so it must be O(2^N).
As John pointed out in comment, the concat/print functions are propotional to N.

together this is O((M^2)*N*(2^N))

Comment: 2^N is a *lower bound* on how many operations are being performed. If the `else:` block operated in constant time it'd be accurate, but due to the string concatenations not being O(1) the answer is higher than 2^N.

Comment: I am still failing to see the truth of this "The while loop is essentially 1+2+...+M times and O(M^2)". Perhaps I am missing some fundamentals of math here. @BingWang

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, unfortunately, rather nasty. First, we must discuss the `print_01_codes` algorithm's complexity.

In the base case of `num_digits = 0`, the algorithm will do `ϴ(length(current))` since we're printing a string of length `current`. When we are in the recursive case, we will reach the base case a total of `2^num_digits` times and the base-case strings will be length `length(current) + num_digits`. This gives us a lower bound of `Ω((num_digits + length(current)) 2^num_digits)` time. It turns out that this is also an upper bound on the time, since at every node of the recursion tree `O(length(current + num_digits))` work is done, so the `print_01_codes` algorithm takes `ϴ((num_digits + length(current)) 2^num_digits)` time.

Analysing the loops, we see that we will call `print_01_codes('', n)` a total of `ϴ(m^2)` times. This will give us a total of `ϴ(n m^2 2^n)` time.